# Same primary key for multiple tables

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create an entity in Symfony2 that the primary key based on another table, but I am getting the following error when trying to run the data fixtures.

> [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]
>
> Entity of type Ofdan\SearchBundle\Entity\CacheHeader is missing an assigned ID. The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="cacheHeader")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class CacheHeader
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Domain", inversedBy="domains")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="domainId", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $domain;

...

}
```

The data fixture I'm using loads in the domain, which should be setting the domainId, which should mean there is an Id.

```
class CacheHeaderFixtures extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $cacheHeader1 = new CacheHeader();
        $cacheHeader1->setDomain($manager->merge($this->getReference('bbc-domain')));
        $cacheHeader1->setDate(new \DateTime());
        $cacheHeader1->setPage(10); // CacheHeader::Page_Index
        $cacheHeader1->setHeader('');
        $manager->persist($cacheHeader1);
    }
}
```

How can I get my CacheHeader entity to work with the domainId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the above works.

The reason I had issue was I had an second fixture, but called setDomain on the wrong object.